# Cannot get Google Drive App Data folder content using query anymore

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

For some reason the following Android app code

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive drive;
...
drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'appdata' in parents").execute().getItems();
```

started returning empty list since May 14. This code was returning my custom folders for more than 1 year before.
I can see my App Data content still exists through

https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive > Settings > Manage Apps.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What is your SCOPE (DRIVE or DRIVE_FILE, ...)?

Comment: Scopes are: DriveScopes.DRIVE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA

Comment: Unfortunately don't have any experience with DRIVE_APPDATA, I've run into a weird scenario with [DRIVE_FILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172915/user-disconnecting-app-in-drive-causes-loss-of-data-under-file-scope) You may double-check if it isn't the same symptom. Or try to switch to the DRIVE scope temporarily.Long shot, though.

Comment: We've reproduced this issue internally and are taking corrective actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a caching issue specifically for App Folder content that affected list queries.

The issue has now been rectified. Thanks for reporting.

Writes were not affected.

Comment: Thanks for addressing this!

Answer (score 1):

The issue still occurs. LIST method doesn't work for newly created files in Application Data Folder. After few hours LIST method returns those files.

Comment: True. But I could not get even the OLD content of App Data folder yesterday. Today it seems to be working, but the new content remains "hidden" for the list() method for some time.