# Google Drive API - LIST method doesn't work for newly created files in App Data Folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm Android developer. I'm using Google Drive Java API to access files in hidden Application Data Folder. Since 14 May 2015, LIST method doesn't return newly created files. Also in the Web interface "Hidden data size" is 0. 
Files are created correctly (response 200 OK, file created), but I can't list them.
I was using LIST method for 2 years and everything was fine until tomorrow. After few hours files are listed by LIST method, but I want access them immediately after create. 
When I save files into visible data folder everything is fine, but problem is with hidden Application Data Folder.
Could you please help me?

Regards

Comment: Recently this same issue was asked here but cant find it. Look in the drive issues page. I remember reading in that question that once you get the file (by id) listing works again.

Comment: We've reproduced this issue internally and are taking corrective actions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get Google Drive App Data folder content using query anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249968/cannot-get-google-drive-app-data-folder-content-using-query-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

This was a caching issue specifically for App Folder content that affected list queries.

We've rectified the issue so you should no longer see this issue. Thanks for reporting.

Writes were not affected.