# How to change permission of folder or file created in Google Drive using Google Drive Android API?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using *`Google Drive Android API`* to store and share files and folders created. When I create a file/folder using *`Google Drive Android API`*,by default created file or folder is **private (not shared publicly)**.

When I share the link of file/folder created to any user, that user needs to send email request for access to owner. So owner have to make file/folder public manually in Google Drive to prevent access requests.

Where as for *`Google Drive iOS API`*, when a file/folder is created, the file/folder created is by default **public**.

Another question I want to ask is, When I am querying list of folders in Root folder (with **`MIME_TYPE`** as **`application/vnd.google-apps.folder`**), the result is given with all folders. Where as using **`Google Drive iOS API`**, **`queryForFilesList()`** method returns only folders created by particular iOS app, not all folders in the root directory.

What I have to do to get this kind of result using **`Google Drive Android API`** or **`Google Drive REST API`**?

Comment: have your app patch the file permissions after the insert.  Its a bug

Comment: How to add permission for files. I don't find any description for adding permissions for files/folders on `Google Drive Android API` documentation.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch  check patch body. permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But that is for **`Google Drive REST API`**, not for **`Google Drive Android API`**.

Comment: Its pretty much the same thing you know.  All I am doing is giving you an idea what to Google for, finding your own answer can be very rewarding.  Feel free to wait for someone else to give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per DaImTo's comment:
You can use [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) and [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) together, I have a side-by-side CRUD implementations published [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) and [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo). You must be aware of a few things, though:

1/ The 'connect' in the GDAA is not aligned with the 'UserRecoverableAuthIOException' logic of the REST See [init](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/REST.java#L62)()/[connect](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/GDAA.java#L69)() combo in the two examples. Actually, you can use GDAA's 'connect' logic to do the authorization and then continue using the REST service. The 'UserRecoverableAuthIOException' should still be handled in case your user messes with the '[Settings > Manage Apps > Disconnect From Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172915/user-disconnecting-app-in-drive-causes-loss-of-data-under-file-scope)'. But then, your app is DOA anyway if it is under the FILE scope.

2/ The GDAA uses DriveId as a primary ID that is local to a device. It has access to the ResourceId (with some latency) that is primary ID in REST. The ResourceID is a system-wide ID that can be ported to different devices, systems. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030110/cannot-get-folderid-that-i-just-created-on-google-drive/29049474#29049474) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269).

3/ The REST API is broader, the GDAA is build on top of it and has only a subset of functionality (no thumbnail link for instance). It supports FILE scope only (as opposed to DRIVE and FILE scopes of the REST).

4/ When you start mixing the 2 together, you will be exposed to latency/timing issues, since your app has full control over the REST's networking, whereas GDAA's synchronization is hidden with some vaguely documented [sync methods](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive-android-api%5D+requestsync).

If you look closer at the GDAA's architecture here ([Lifecycle of a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files)) , you will figure out potential pitfalls of mixing the two.

Good Luck