# Google Drive selected file share link permissions change in android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I am working on Google Drive integration in my Android application. I'm able to get the "shared link" for the selected Google Drive file, but that shared link does not have permission to be viewed by all Google accounts. I want to change the permission to public so that anyone can view it.

I am using the new Google Drive API, which is a part of Google Play Services.
I am using code from the following link:
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

Comment: Have you already checked out https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing? I think you should be able to do it by setting `type` to "anyone" and `role` to "reader".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change permission of folder or file created in Google Drive using Google Drive Android API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389302/how-to-change-permission-of-folder-or-file-created-in-google-drive-using-google)

Comment: Currently you would need to use the Google Drive Web API to update permissions.