# Filters.ownedByMe doesn't work in 'Drive API for Android' (But works correctly in 'API Client Library for Java')

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Previously, I'm using "API Client Library for Java" to perform file search in appdata folder.

### File searching code in API Client Library for Java

```
private static void searchFromGoogleDrive(Drive drive, String qString) {
    try {
        Files.List request = drive.files().list().setQ(qString);

        do {                
            FileList fileList = request.execute();

            for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f : fileList.getItems()) {

                final String title = f.getTitle();

                if (title == null || f.getDownloadUrl() == null || f.getDownloadUrl().length() <= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                ...
            }

            request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(null, ex);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

It works perfectly fine for the following query string.

```
title contains 'jstock-fe78440e-e0fe-4efb' and trashed = false and 'appdata' in parents and 'me' in owners
```

Recently, I try to migrate the code to use "Drive API for Android". I have 2 scopes for `GoogleApiClient`

- Drive.SCOPE_FILE
- Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER

### File searching code in Drive API for Android

```
private static void searchFromGoogleDrive(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    DriveFolder driveFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient);

    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.and(
                Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, "jstock-fe78440e-e0fe-4efb"),
                Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false),
                Filters.ownedByMe()
            ))
            .build();

    DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult = driveFolder.queryChildren(googleApiClient, query).await();

    if (metadataBufferResult == null) {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "metadataBufferResult is null");
    } else {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "metadataBufferResult's status = " + metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess());
    }

    if (metadataBufferResult != null && metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = null;
        try {
            metadataBuffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
            if (metadataBuffer != null ) {
                for (Metadata md : metadataBuffer) {
                    if (md == null || !md.isDataValid()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Log.i("CHEOK", "title = " + md.getTitle());
                }   // for
            }   // if
        } finally {
            if (metadataBuffer != null) {
                metadataBuffer.release();
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I realize, `Filters.ownedByMe` is the one which causes the problem.

Here's the different outcomes based on different Queries.

### Failed

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.and(
            Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, "jstock-fe78440e-e0fe-4efb"),
            Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false),
            Filters.ownedByMe()
        ))
        .build();            
// metadataBufferResult's status = false
```

### Failed

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.and(
            Filters.ownedByMe()
        ))
        .build();
// metadataBufferResult's status = false
```

### Success

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.and(
            Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, "jstock-fe78440e-e0fe-4efb"),
            Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)
        ))
        .build();    
// metadataBufferResult's status = true
// title = jstock-fe78440e-e0fe-4efb-881d-264a01be483c-checksum=2298926779-date=1452429908167-version=1107.zip
```

*It seems that `Filters.ownedByMe()` doesn't work as correctly in Drive API for Android*

Is there anything I can rectify this?

Comment: What does 'ownedByMe'  without any other filters return? I would recommend to post it on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-DriveAndroid) to get attention.

Comment: 'ownedByMe' without any other filters will return false in getStatus().isSuccess()

Comment: Looks to me you've done enough testing for the 'issue tracker' step.

Comment: Why would you need `ownedByMe` at all? If you're only looking at files in the appdata directory, those can only be created/found by your app.

Comment: The reason ownedByMe is there, as we just direct port from previous "API Client Library for Java"'s code. The previous code tend to be generic - it performs search in appdata folder & non appdata folder. Hence, "'me' in owners" is essential when searching in non appdata folder. For my current case which operates only in appdata, I think I can remove ownedByMe. But, it doesn't explain why ownedByMe is broken in "Drive API for Android"

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Just a side note. I spent 3 months porting from REST to GDAA just to throw it all away because of timing issues. Also, GooPlaySvcs upgrades messed up things without warning (like getting 'unspecified GooPlaySvc error' that would go away 2 hours later, etc). This situation may improve after awhile, but GDAA's been around for 2 years now ... And the SO support is close to nonexistent (just compare the [FIREBASE tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase+firebase-android) with the [GDAA tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-android-api))

Comment: It does look like a bug. I've created an issue on Google's API issue tracker: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4241

Comment: @seanpj the reason i want to migrate from REST to GDAA is that, I want to avoid runtime permission from Android 6.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639890/google-drive-api-the-name-must-not-be-empty-null-but-i-had-passed-valid-acco